# How can I make a copy of a DB instance to use as a test/sandbox DB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, relational-database, instance, sandbox

I have multiple questions about this issue since AWS is still new to me.

What I am trying to accomplish: I want to create a test/sandbox db for my live db instance. I want to do this to create a sandbox environment for my developers, so they can add, edit, delete whatever they want on the test db without effecting the companies live db that's being used for our site.

Specifications: I want my test db to be continually updated alongside my live db. So I want a parent and child relationship or master/slave. So basically whatever the master has the slave will have but the slave cannot edit the master in any way whatsoever. Also I want the slave to have a different security group than the masters.

Things I have tried: first I thought I could copy a db snapshot of my live db and transfer it to a new db instance. But how would the new instance be continually updated. I couldn't even find what to do with the copied snapshot so that was a dead end.
Then I read that I could create a read replica of my master db, so I did that, I promoted it as per the documentation. Now can I read and write to this replica? Is this the correct path for what I want? Can I assign the replica a different security group from the master? And will the replica get updated data from master?

Is what I'm asking possible? Could someone please explain to me what the correct course of action is here or if I'm going about it incorrectly.
Again a bit lost as I'm new to AWS, any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Documentation for reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html

Comment: You want to have test DB as the exact copy of prod DB, and have developers write/edit it at the same time?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be exact, it can be a few hours behind or even a day really.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with RDS. Either you use replication (and can't write to replica) or make a clone that will not update.

You can, however, setup you own MySQL/MariaDB master-slave configuration and write to slave. Should work fine as long as you don't have conflicting values in indexes (usually because of autoincrementing primary key).

Comment: Can I make a clone that I can manually update with snapshots?

Comment: You cannot "update" clone from snapshots. You can only create new clone from a more recent snapshot.

Comment: Could you provide documentation or a link as to how create a clone that can write from a snapshot. I'm having a lot of trouble navigating AWS. Thank you.

Comment: Is there something I can read that can explain to me how to navigate and perform task in AWS, something for beginners, right now I'm so lost and confused.

Comment: It's all in the official docs. Create snapshot: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html. Restore snapshot in new DB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html